# Plot temperature data by season + R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, temperature

I created a subset by season from an initial dataset representing temperature over time.

Here, it's an example of Summer. When I plot my seasonal temperature data over time, I got the following graph.

I don't understand why I have "unstructured lines" while I don't have any NA values in my dataset.

`dput(head(Summer[, c(1, 3)]))`

`` structure(list(`Nb enr` = c(152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157), Date = structure(c(4169,  4170, 4171, 4172, 4173, 4174), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,  -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) ``

```
ggplot(., aes(x = Date, y = Geneve_temp_C)) +
  geom_line(color="#339999", na.rm = T)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black") +
  stat_cor(label.y = 35)+ #this means at 35th unit in the y axis, the r squared and p value will be shown
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 30)+
  labs(x = "Time (days)", y="Temperature (°C") + labs(title = "Température journalière à Genève 1980-2010")
```

[image]

I would like this output
[image]

Comment: There is a single green/blue line going across the image. Since you only have summer temperatures, the line jumps from the last day of summer every year to the first day of summer the next year in a straight line. It then jumps up and down during the summer days. What output are you expecting? You might want to try `geom_line(color="#339999", na.rm = T, aes(group = lubridate::year(Date))) +`

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you. I updated my post with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This problem often means there is some grouping characteristic missing from the graphic. At the end of the post, I show you how to avoid this.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(df, aes(
  x = Date,
  y = Geneve_temp_C,
  color = `Nb enr`,
  group = 1
)) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black") +
  stat_cor(label.y = 35) + #this means at 35th unit in the y axis, the r squared and p value will be shown
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = 30) +
  labs(x = "Time (days)", y = "Precipitation (mm d-1)") + labs(title = "Précipitation journalière à Genève 1980-2010")+
theme_pander() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      hjust = 1,
      face = "bold",
      size = 12,
      color = "black"
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "black"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(
      family = "Times",
      color = "black",
      size = 16,
      face = "bold"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Sample code:

```
   df <- structure(
  list(
    `Nb enr` = c(152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157),
    Geneve_temp_C = c(10, 23, 24, 25, 30, 23),
    Date = structure(c(4169,  4170, 4171, 4172, 4173, 4174), class = "Date")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

An example of how to avoid this. I create a dummy dataset of 8 products over the course of 12 days, with the product prices chosen at random.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(0)

date <- Sys.Date()
df <- data.frame(
  date = rep(seq(date - 11, date, by = "1 day"), 8),
  change_price = as.vector(replicate(8, cumsum(rnorm(12)))),
  products = rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 12)
)
```

You get the sawtooth pattern I mentioned earlier when we plot this in the same manner as you did.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

  ggplot(df, aes(date, change_price)) +
  geom_line(size=2)+
  labs(x="Date", y="Price")+
  theme_pander() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      hjust = 1,
      face = "bold",
      size = 12,
      color = "black"
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "black"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(
      family = "Times",
      color = "black",
      size = 16,
      face = "bold"
    )
  )
```

Plot:

[image]

It is possible to remove the sawtooth pattern by setting a group aesthetic that specifies that each product has its own set of lines to draw.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)  

 
ggplot(df, aes(date, change_price)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = products), size=2)+
  labs(x="Date", y="Price")+
  theme_pander() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      hjust = 1,
      face = "bold",
      size = 12,
      color = "black"
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "black"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(
      family = "Times",
      color = "black",
      size = 16,
      face = "bold"
    )
  )
```

Plot:

[image]

or color your lines

```
aes(color=products)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Arys, thank you for your effort. I updated the expected results. I tried your code but it gives me the same output.